# How does one find possible values for com_microsoft_outlook_categories in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

After reading a couple of StackExchange answers, I have come to understand that Outlook 2016 on Mac does not support searching with the OR operator other than through raw queries. Since I want to create Smart Folders from multiple email categories, I need to figure out what the numeric categories are for my category labels.

Does anyone know how to retrieve possible values for `com_microsoft_outlook_categories` or `com_microsoft_outlook_primaryCategory`?

Comment: I did much research but failed to find a raw query reference. According to the discussion in the link below,  you may need to use mdls command to get the category ID for the category.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5803575

Comment: Okay, using mdls on Outlook messages worked to get the category numbers. For Outlook 2016, messages were in the following folder:

`~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Messages`

I applied all of my categories to a single message and then grep'ed the email subject for that message to find the file:

`grep -r -i "Example Subject Line" ./*`

which returned the message name:

`Binary file ./14/ExampleName.olk15Message matches`

I ran mdls on that file, and looked in the `com_microsoft_outlook_categories` section for my categories.